# Multiple edittext in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

We're making an app which makes it possible to share group costs.
In order to do this you can select people with whom you would like to share the next bill.
I made a sort of "list-view-item" which contains a "Debit" and "Credit" field for each user and added these items to a Recyclerview according to how many people are sharing the payment.
However, now i am trying to read all the values that were entered in these edittexts but i don't know how.
The code that generates the the list in the recyclerview is the following:

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
    rvTransactions = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvTransactions);
    lmTransactions = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvTransactions.setLayoutManager(lmTransactions);
    transactionAdapter = new RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {
        @Override
        public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_transaction, viewGroup, false);
            return new CustomViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            viewHolder.noticeSubject.setText(participatingUsers.get(i).getFirstname() + " " + participatingUsers.get(i).getLastname());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return participatingUsers.size();
        }

    };
    rvTransactions.setAdapter(transactionAdapter);
}

private class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView noticeSubject;
    private EditText userDebt,userCredit;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        noticeSubject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionUser);
        userCredit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTransactionPayed);
        userDebt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTransactionOwes);
    }
}
```

The participatingUsers object is a list of users.
A user has the following fields:

```
private int id;
private boolean isSelected;
private String firstname, lastname, email, password, api_key, creditcardnumber;
```

[image: This is what the view looks like, you can see the "payed" and "owes" fields that were added dynamicly]

I want to be able to get the values that were entered in the edittexts "payed" and "owes" for all the users.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do

Comment: I want to be able to get the values that were entered in the edittexts "payed" and "owes" for all the users. Sorry should have made that clearer in the post.

Comment: so each element in the recycler view is a edit text and you want to read that.

Comment: please share your participatingusers object...

Comment: There are two Edittext fields in each element, and yes i want to be able to read them all

Comment: The participatingusers object is a List<User> object. I'll also ad it to the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop over the childCount of the RecyclerView and check to make sure the item your reading is of type CustomViewHolder, cast to that type and read EditText Values. Something like:

```
 public void printAllEditTextValues(){
     int childCount = rvTransactions.getChildCount(); 
     for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
         if(rvTransactions.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) instanceOf CustomViewHolder){
           CustomViewHolder childHolder = (CustomViewHolder) rvTransactions.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);

           Log.d("EDIT_TEXT_1" , childHolder.userCredit.getText().toString());
           Log.d("EDIT_TEXT_2" , childHolder.userDebt.getText().toString());
         }
     }
```

your adapter is missing thie itemView.findViewById(int) for your edit text, use:

```
private class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView noticeSubject;
    private EditText userDebt,userCredit;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        noticeSubject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTransactionUser);
        userCredit = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etTransactionPayed);
        userDebt = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etTransactionOwes);
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand and it seems like the perfect solution, however the "instanceof" the rvTransactions.getChildAt(i) returns a View instead of a CustomViewHolder.
It could be that i'm not seeing an obvious solution here but i'm fairly new to the android coding world.

Comment: @BramVandenbogaerde ahh, i missed that check my update which should work for you

Comment: @BramVandenbogaerde is getText().toString() reading a null value out ? is this maybe because your checking their value when the field is still empty? can you post stacktrace

Comment: i found it, i made a LinearLayout(vertical) for the list item containing the Textview and another LinearLayout(horizontal) containing both edittexts. 
So i created an object for the LinearLayout and then just got the childAt(1) and childAt(2). I know it probably isn't the cleanest and proper way but it seems to work out for now.

Comment: @BramVandenbogaerde i see the issue please see the update above, no need to do that extra work

Comment: This is amazing man, thanks so much for the help. Would have taken me hours to figure this out. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @BramVandenbogaerde no problem please accept if this was the solution to your problem.

Comment: Even I am also looking for the same solution. But I have one doubt, is it good to pass viewholder to fragment where recyclerview resides. The fragment should know nothing about viewholder.  It violates the law of Demeter. Please share your views. Until then I am with text watcher approach.

Comment: @RaghavSharma certainly you are right that this is not the BEST way to do this. But given the problem this is a valid solution (despite it breaking LoD). A better approach would be to add the payed and owes fields to the User object, listen to text changes via a TextWatcher (knowning the position of the edited item in the RecyclerView) update that Object at the position and iterate the List<User> on button submission.